# results about increasing sequence of probability spaces

Tags: probability

I have an increasing sequence of probability spaces, $A_i$, for e.g. increasing sequence of finite subsets $A_i$ of $\mathbb{N}$, with sigma algebra generated by singletons, and $P_{A_i}(x) = |A_i|^{-1}$ for each $x\in A_i$, along with random variables $X_i$ on $A_i$.

If $X_i$'s satisfy some nice property, do there exists results that will allow me to say something about that property in the limit, for example, $A_i$ could be $[i]$, and the nice property could be that with high probability some fraction of them are primes. I would think that such questions would arise naturally in lots of places, so maybe there are results of this sort known.

Everything in my toolbox seems to apply to increasing sequence of events in a some fixed probability space. But in my setting of $\mathbb{N}$, the limiting space is not even a probability space in any manner that would reconcile with $A_i$'s.

Comment: Is this question akin to what is the probability of choosing a prime number vs what is the probability of choosing an even number in N?

Comment: I suppose there's a way to make that analogy, but I am more interested in 0/1 laws about X_i